# How to add jquery transition effects to html5 details tag

Tags: html, jquery, html-tag-details

I wished to use HTML5 `<details>` for my [FAQ page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ) where i need to display  only the questions at the begining.  and for this've found a [jquery fallback plugin for other browsers](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-details-jquery)  (currently only chrome supports).

```
<details>
   <summary>My FAQ question here</summary>
   <pFaq answer here</p>
</details>
```

Now is it possible to give the effect other than the default for the toggling the answer of the FAQ possible with the help of  jQuery.

Thanks in advance.